# echo language construct is discouraged. (PHP)

Tags: php, codacy, github-codereviews

why codacy(code review tool) showing "echo language construct is discouraged."

how to solve this issue.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXmDv.png): [image]

Comment: dup? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/162503/magento-marketplace-code-validation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either:

**Replace `echo` with `print_r`:**

```
print_r( $StateList->state_name )
```

**Return the value instead:**

```
return $StateList->state_name
```

As for why your linter discourages the use of `echo`, this depends on your coding standard and context.

For example, if you wish to follow the [PSR-1 Basic Coding Standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/), [section 2.3](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/#23-side-effects) states that:

> A file SHOULD declare new symbols (classes, functions, constants, etc.) and cause no other side effects, or it SHOULD execute logic with side effects, but SHOULD NOT do both.

Since `echo` produces a side effect, it would be discouraged in the context of a file that was declaring a new class, for instance. In this context, you'd return the value instead.

Answer (score 0):

Codacy detects linting problems on your code base. Linting problems may be security bugs, code style issues, etc.

In your case, it's bad practice to use php "echo". Just like you shouldn't use `println` in other languages. If you need to print something, you should use loggers